# Smart pointer gets prematurely deleted due to GTest teardown

Tags: c++, pointers, googletest, googlemock

I am currently refactoring codes to make raw pointers use smart pointers and also making test for this class but stuck with an issue of a smart pointer being prematurely deleted

Here is an example:

```
class SomeObjectType
{
public:
   void init()
   {
   }
};

class Helper
{
public:
    Helper()
    {
        std::cout << "Helper constructor" << std::endl;
       //some codes
    }
    ~Helper()
    {
        std::cout << "Helper destructor" << std::endl;
       //some codes
    }
    SomeObjectType* createObject()
    {
        return new SomeObjectType;
      //some codes
    }
    void destroyObject(SomeObjectType* obj)
    {
       //some codes
    }
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
       helper = std::make_shared<Helper>();
    }
    ~Base()
    {
       destroyObject(obj);
    }
    void Init()
    {
       obj = createObject();
    }
    SomeObjectType* createObject()
    {
       return helper->createObject();
    }
    void destroyObject(SomeObjectType* obj)
    {
       helper->destroyObject(obj); // <-- I get the error here
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Helper> helper;

private:
    SomeObjectType* obj;

FRIEND_TEST(BaseTest , Init_handleSuccess);
};
```

And in my test:

```
class BaseTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp()
    {
        sut_ = std::make_unique<Base>();
        helperMock_ = std::make_shared<HelperMock>();
        //helperMock_ = new HelperMock;  //it works when I dont use smart pointers but of course there is a leak here
    }

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> sut_;
    std::shared_ptr<HelperMock> helperMock_;
    //HelperMock* helperMock_; //it works when I dont use smart pointers but of course there is a leak here
};

TEST_F(BaseTest, Init_handleSuccess)
{
    auto obj = new SomeObjectType();
    sut_->helper.reset(helperMock_.get());
    EXPECT_EQ(S_OK, sut_->Init());
}
```

When I checked the logs, I see that this is what happens (in this order):

- Test setup called
- Base constructor called
- Helper constructor called
- Test teardown
- Helper destructor called
- Base destructor called
- Base destructor tries to access `helper` which was already deleted = crash!

So basically `helper` pointer was already deleted prior to call of `destroyObject()` because its life was tied with my test. So when I change the test to use a raw pointer for `helper`, I do not get the double delete but then it becomes a leak since I didnt delete `helper` at all :)  What can I do so that `helper` is still alive when the base class destructor is  called?

Note: There is some API calls I need inside the helper's `createObject` that is why I am mocking it. I can't inject helper as a dependency that is why I have to 'hack' it with `sut_->helper.reset(helperMock_.get());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might be your issue...

```
sut_->helper.reset(helperMock_);
```

I'm not even sure how that code above could possibly be compiling, because I thought that `reset` expects a raw pointer for the shared_ptr to take ownership of.  (And as you updated in the comments: you were really invoking reset with .get() ).

And the biggest mistake you can make with a shared_ptr is to invoke .get() or use `*` operator - and pass the returned raw pointer to initialize another shared_ptr. Now you got two different reference counting sessions on the same object. Which ever set of shared_ptr instances goes away first will delete the object. Leaving the other set of shared_ptrs referencing an already deleted object.

Replace the above with just this:

```
sut_->helper = helperMock_;
```

I'm assuming HelperMock derives from Helper.

Comment: OMG you're a lifesaver. Thank you so much, this works!

Comment: I still don't understand how that `sut_->helper.reset(helperMock_);` could have compiled to begin with.  Unless you were really using `helper.reset(*helperMock_);` or `helper.reset(helperMock_.get());`

Comment: Yes, I was using helperMock.get() for the reset. My bad, I only created the above codes for this question and not the actual one I'm working on.

Comment: Glad to help - but you really need to show exact code when you post a question like this. The `.get()` would have been the tip-off from the start.